# How to handle compound keys with Spring Data JDBC

Tags: java, spring-data, compound-key, spring-data-jdbc

I'm trying to use Spring Data JDBC to access a table that has a compound key, and although I can find lots of info on how Spring Data JPA handles this, the same doesn't seem to apply to Spring Data JDBC.

Can anyone give a quick example of how you need to declare an Entity/Repository with Spring Data JDBC to talk to a table with a compound primary key ? (Eg. Two Strings)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composite Key and spring-data-jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513863/composite-key-and-spring-data-jdbc)

Answer (score 2):

Using the CrudRepository for compound keys is currently (Version 1.0.2) not possible.

Of course, you can still use methods annotated with `@Query`.

Comment: I tried, but I have to declare at least something with `@Id`, or it refuses to read the data, and if I do that, then updates are issued with an incorrect where clause. 

I've ended up having to reimplement 'save' in my own class, using separate insert & update methods on the repository that have to accept each column as a named parameter because (I think?) spring-data-jdbc doesn't support spel in `@query` currently, so I can't just pass my dao & access the fields from the `@query`. 

If you have a better suggestion for a workaround for how perform 'save', I'd be very interested!

Comment: @Jens Schauder Is there any change as of today ? Are compound keys still not supported?

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov unfortunately not.

Comment: @JensSchauder any plans on supporting  this ? I noticed Embedded annotation is already in the milestone branch.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov Absolutely! Actually, I'm building/fixing/improving infrastructure right now that will help to make this possible. That said: I currently don't think it will make it into the 1.1 release.

Could you create a ticket for it at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC