# Composite Key and spring-data-jdbc

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I have a database which is using composite keys. Is it possible to utilize spring-data-jdbc? I tried the milestone version 1.1M2 where I mapped my entity in the following way:

```
class History {

   @ID
   @Embedded
   private CompositeHistoryID  id;
}
```

Then in my repository class, I added

```
HistoryRepository extends Repository<History,CompositeHistoryID  >{
   History  findByhId(CompositeHistoryID  id)
}
```

I traced the SQL, and it did not work. The embedded part worked, but the where clause was not correct. It was using a single parameter holder instead of having the regular composite key structure where element1=subkey1 and element2=subkey2 and so on...

I have two questions. Is there any way to make the Composite ID work?

The second question is, let's suppose that I use a custom `@Query` on top of the `findByID` will the SAVE method work after that if? What is there is no ID at all, what if I just pick a random column and say you will be my ID?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53345366/how-to-handle-compound-keys-with-spring-data-jdbc/53346069#comment97738382_53346069

Comment: Bummer that https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-352 was created over a year ago and such a fundamental feature has still not made it into a release.

Comment: @ccampo upvote, hopefuly the right person will notice one day :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No `@Embedded` doesn't work for Ids, [yet](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-352).
Right now all SQL statements assume a simple value for the id column.
And I don't think there is a workaround for that.

One workaround that might work is to create a view that presents the composite key as a single field and has triggers writing the correct data into the underlying table.

Comment: Thats really bad and makes Spring Data JDBC useless for most database schemas :(

Comment: @PowerStar i think you are exgagerating a bit :) But it is Indeed invonvinient if you have legacy database or natural key.

Comment: So the only way to use spring-jdbc with such tables is to add a synthetic simple-type ID column to the tables used?

Answer (score -1):

For (hopefully) the few Aggregate Roots needing composite Id's, you can always use a fragment repository to provide own implementation either by overriding relevant methods from (List)CrudRepository - or just use Repository. (You can still create queries like `findAllByLastname` etc.

A actual workaround where you dont need to write a fragment repository (or similar) is to model this in a Set/Map. This way, in the database schema for the table related to the aggregate root (or further down the hierarchy) could have composite primary keys. Queries can be created querying this table directly based on the composite primary key, and you can probably create a insert as well.
In the application where I have actually done this, I created an embeddable wrapper-object containing only the Set (Map actually) just to provide an interface to work with this.

```
import java.util.*

data class Userdata(
    @Id val id: UUID,
    val keyValueStore: Set<UserdataKeyValue> 
)

data class UserdataKeyValue(
    val key: String,
    val value: String
)

CREATE TABLE USERDATA_KEY_VALUE
(         
    userdata uuid not null,
    key varchar(30) not null,
    value varchar(255)
);

ALTER TABLE USERDATA_KEY_VALUE
  ADD CONSTRAINT pk_KEY_VALUE_TO_USERDATA
    PRIMARY KEY (userdata, key);
```